# VisualForce - Page Leave Alert

Tags: visualforce

Can someone help me code a page leave alert for VF?

I found this code for commandbuttons:

`onclick="if(!confirm('Did you do everything?')){return};"`

which generates a prompt on the page which is exactly what I want except I need this to occur on page leave instead of on a button click.

My goal is to prevent a user from leaving the page without saving.

I have found the code below online but I am not sure how to swap out the function(e) for the action above. I want to use the Salesforce alert as the browser will always display my text instead of the hit or miss results I get from this code in different browsers.

```
<script>
    var LeaveAllowed = false;
    var evt = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var checkEvt = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';
    evt(checkEvt, function(e) {
        if (!LeaveAllowed)
        {
            var msg = 'There may be unsaved changes.';
            (e || window.event).returnValue = msg;
            return msg;
        }
    });

    function allowLeave()
    {
        LeaveAllowed = true;
    }

</script>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: did you also look at http://michaelwelburn.com/2013/04/08/confirming-a-user-really-wants-to-leave-a-visualforce-page/ ?

Comment: That is similar to what I have above and is along the right path but instead of using the browser popup alert which behaves differently in IE,Chrome, Firefox, etc I want to use the apex confirm prompt which always displays the same way.